# Get directory path n deph long of a given root path

Tags: c#, path

I am looking for a better/safer/more elegant generic method that could give me an n depth long directory from a given path.

I've created something that works but it based on string parsing so I hope you could find a better solution. The method could use a directory info for passed/returned values as well.

```
public static string GetDirectoryNDepth(string root, string target, int depth)
    {
        string[] splittedRoot = root.Split('\\');
        string[] splittedTarget = target.Split('\\');

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < splittedTarget.Length; i++)

            if (i < splittedRoot.Count() + depth)
                sb.Append(String.Format("{0}\\", splittedTarget[i]));
            else
                break;

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Sample values:

```
        //For 3 depth long parametr it should return expected value
        //First case filepath
        string root = @"C\Desktop\temp\MSC\IH";
        string target = @"C:\Desktop\temp\MSC\IH\FirstLevel\SecondLevel\ThirdLevel\dsf - Copy (2).xml";
        string expected = @"C:\Desktop\temp\MSC\IH\FirstLevel\SecondLevel\ThirdLevel";

        //Second case target shorter then depth
        string root = @"C\Desktop\temp\MSC\IH";
        string target = @"C:\Desktop\temp\MSC\IH\FirstLevel\SecondLevel";
        string expected = @"C:\Desktop\temp\MSC\IH\FirstLevel\SecondLevel";
```

Comment: It works. What else do you want it to do?

Comment: I am not sure if it will work with all UNC paths and looking for a way to solve a problem through directoryInfo class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, instead of using `\` as the separator, you can use [Path.DirectorySeparatorChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead like this

```
public  string GetDirectoryNDepth(string root, string target, int depth)
{
    string[] splittedRoot = root.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
    string[] splittedTarget = target.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < splittedTarget.Length; i++)

         if (i < splittedRoot.Length + depth)
            sb.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", splittedTarget[i], Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));
         else
            break;

    return sb.ToString(); 
}
```

From the `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` doc:

> Provides a platform-specific character used to separate directory
>   levels in a path string that reflects a hierarchical file system
>   organization...
>
> ...The value of this field is a slash ("/") on UNIX, and a backslash
>   ("\") on the Windows and Macintosh operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

I found input set very particular that root doesn't start with C: it is C\

don't know whether it is purposefully like that

```
string root = @"C\Desktop\temp\MSC\IH";
string target = @"C:\Desktop\temp\MSC\IH\FirstLevel\SecondLevel\ThirdLevel\dsf - Copy (2).xml";
string expected = @"C:\Desktop\temp\MSC\IH\FirstLevel\SecondLevel\ThirdLevel";
```

Based upon input sample & code this would be efficient code

```
    public static string GetDirectoryNDepth(string root, string target, int depth)
    {
        var separatorChar = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;

        int rootSlashCount = root.Split(separatorChar).Length;
        int totalSlashCount = rootSlashCount + depth;


        var iCnt = root.Length;
        while(iCnt < target.Length  && rootSlashCount <= totalSlashCount)
        {
            if (target[iCnt] == separatorChar)
                rootSlashCount++;
            iCnt++;
        }

        var retVal = target.Substring(0, iCnt);
        if (retVal.EndsWith(separatorChar+"") == false)
            retVal += separatorChar;
        return retVal;

    }
```